# Connecting to host's secondary IP from inside docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, networking

I'm migrating an existing AWS (ubuntu) + Docker configuration to start using an Elastic Network Interface, so that I have persistent IPs in DNS.  At boot time of the instance, I attach the ENI and it works great:

```
  aws ec2 attach-network-interface --network-interface-id ${ENI} --instance-id ${INSTANCE_ID} --region ${REGION} --device-index 1

  ETH1=/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1.cfg
  echo "auto eth1" > ${ETH1}
  echo "iface eth1 inet dhcp" >> ${ETH1}
  echo " up ip route add default via ${INSTANCE_SUBNET}.1 dev eth1 tab 2" >> ${ETH1}
  echo " up ip rule add from ${IP2}/32 tab 2" >> ${ETH1}
  echo " up ip rule add to ${IP2}/32 tab 2" >> ${ETH1}
  echo " up ip route flush cache" >> ${ETH1}
  ifup eth1
```

I'm successfully able to ping and ssh to the ENI address on eth1 remotely as well as locally on the host.  It all works great.  Except... Docker.  From inside a container, I can connect to the host's eth0 interface, but not eth1.  (For the purpose of this post, **eth0==.207** and **eth1==.213**.)

On the host, which boots up as .207:

```
[root@10.180.11.207 ~]$ ping 10.180.11.207
PING 10.180.11.207 (10.180.11.207) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.180.11.207: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from 10.180.11.207: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
^C
--- 10.180.11.207 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.028/0.033/0.039/0.008 ms
[root@10.180.11.207 ~]$ ping 10.180.11.213
PING 10.180.11.213 (10.180.11.213) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.180.11.213: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from 10.180.11.213: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
64 bytes from 10.180.11.213: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
^C
--- 10.180.11.213 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/0.034/0.037/0.007 ms
```

Inside docker:

```
[root@10.180.11.207 ~]$ docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
root@42e0b7d1d484:/# (apt update && apt install -y iputils-ping) > /dev/null
root@42e0b7d1d484:/# ping 10.180.11.207
PING 10.180.11.207 (10.180.11.207) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.180.11.207: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
64 bytes from 10.180.11.207: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
^C
--- 10.180.11.207 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.047/0.050/0.053/0.003 ms
root@42e0b7d1d484:/# ping 10.180.11.213
PING 10.180.11.213 (10.180.11.213) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.180.11.213 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 12095ms

root@42e0b7d1d484:/#
```

Back on the host, it all looks ok to me...

```
[root@10.180.11.207 ~]$ ifconfig -a
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:70:51:aa:6a
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:70ff:fe51:aa6a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:35525 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42531 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2099259 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:120243109 (120.2 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:8c:bb:46:24:10
          inet addr:10.180.11.207  Bcast:10.180.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::48c:bbff:fe46:2410/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:132933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:49069 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:182046681 (182.0 MB)  TX bytes:4131332 (4.1 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:b9:f0:13:06:4a
          inet addr:10.180.11.213  Bcast:10.180.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4b9:f0ff:fe13:64a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:33623 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32080 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1877291 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:14361232 (14.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:244 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:244 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:21188 (21.1 KB)  TX bytes:21188 (21.1 KB)

vethfd8cd11 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:81:86:18:db:f4
          inet6 addr: fe80::a881:86ff:fe18:dbf4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17230 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1340186 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:40751823 (40.7 MB)
```

nothing stands out to me in the route tables

```
[root@10.180.11.207 ~]$ ip route list
default via 10.180.11.1 dev eth0
10.180.11.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.180.11.207
10.180.11.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.180.11.213
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1
```

or iptables

```
[root@10.180.11.207 ~]$ iptables --list

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I can see the packets on docker0.  I don't see anything on eth0 (or eth1) but I'm assuming it should be loopback anyway?

```
[root@10.180.11.207 ~]$ tcpdump -n -i docker0 port not 22
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on docker0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
18:12:44.497216 ARP, Request who-has 172.17.0.2 tell 172.17.0.1, length 28
18:12:44.497274 ARP, Reply 172.17.0.2 is-at 02:42:ac:11:00:02, length 28
18:12:46.522555 IP 172.17.0.2 > 10.180.11.207: ICMP echo request, id 297, seq 1, length 64
18:12:46.522590 IP 10.180.11.207 > 172.17.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 297, seq 1, length 64
18:12:47.521557 IP 172.17.0.2 > 10.180.11.207: ICMP echo request, id 297, seq 2, length 64
18:12:47.521595 IP 10.180.11.207 > 172.17.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 297, seq 2, length 64
18:12:48.521272 IP 172.17.0.2 > 10.180.11.207: ICMP echo request, id 297, seq 3, length 64
18:12:48.521311 IP 10.180.11.207 > 172.17.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 297, seq 3, length 64
18:12:57.207506 IP 172.17.0.2 > 10.180.11.213: ICMP echo request, id 298, seq 1, length 64
18:12:58.215426 IP 172.17.0.2 > 10.180.11.213: ICMP echo request, id 298, seq 2, length 64
18:12:59.223387 IP 172.17.0.2 > 10.180.11.213: ICMP echo request, id 298, seq 3, length 64
18:13:00.231388 IP 172.17.0.2 > 10.180.11.213: ICMP echo request, id 298, seq 4, length 64
18:13:01.239439 IP 172.17.0.2 > 10.180.11.213: ICMP echo request, id 298, seq 5, length 64
18:13:02.247412 IP 172.17.0.2 > 10.180.11.213: ICMP echo request, id 298, seq 6, length 64
18:13:03.255409 IP 172.17.0.2 > 10.180.11.213: ICMP echo request, id 298, seq 7, length 64
```

routing decisions look ok:

```
[root@10.180.11.207 ~]$ ip route get 10.180.11.213 from 172.17.0.1
local 10.180.11.213 from 172.17.0.1 dev lo
    cache <local>
[root@10.180.11.207 ~]$ ip route get 10.180.11.207 from 172.17.0.1
local 10.180.11.207 from 172.17.0.1 dev lo
    cache <local>
[root@10.180.11.207 ~]$ ip route get 10.180.11.213 from 10.180.11.207
local 10.180.11.213 from 10.180.11.207 dev lo
    cache <local>
```

Any ideas?  I've exhausted every trick I know.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue lies in the way the network bridge is configured. docker0 is a bridge to eth0. You need another bridge to eth1 and then attach that bridge to the container as another network.

An example may be:

```
docker network create -d bridge \
--subnet=172.30.0.32/24 \
--opt com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=true \
--opt com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4=10.180.11.213 \
--opt com.docker.network.bridge.name=docker1 \
docker1
```

The important part is the `com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4` which is the eth1 IP.

Then connect the container to that bridge:

```
docker network connect docker1 container-name
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I'm hoping there is a more global approach, as I have hundreds of host systems, of which only some of them have an eth1, which is supposed to be a hidden tweak and not a system detail that the dockerized systems are even aware of.  A global docker change on a system is okay, but per-container would lead me to abandon the entire approach.  :-/